# Внести список list в таблицу sqlite3 с помощью python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(f'user_db/{str(user_id)}.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(ord, orwh, orob, ornm, orsu, oris)""".format('user_data'))
conn.commit()
for j in ord:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user_data (ord) VALUES (?)', [j] )
for k in orwh:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user_data (orwh) VALUES (?)', [k])
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Как правильно модифицировать код, чтобы он вносил данные из нескольких списков? список имеет формат условно `ord = [1,2,3,4] orwh = [11,12,13,14]` данные берутся из json(), количество элементов в списке всегда разное.

На данном этапе, тем кодом который я написал он вносит так, что сначала с 1 по 4 строки в столбец ord, а потом с 5 по 8 строки в столбец orwh. Соответственно в первом столбце 5-8 строки, а во втором 1-4 строки остаются со значением NULL. А мне нужно чтобы он вносил без пропусков, без NULL. Пробовал executemany и сразу поставить и ord и orwh не получилось правильно сделать код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `zip`, хотя правильнее через `executemany` всё-равно.

```
for j,k in zip(ord, orwh):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user_data (ord,orwh) VALUES (?,?)', [j,k] )
```

И `connect` и `cursor` лучше через `with` открывать, примеры есть в документации.

Comment: Благодарю, помогло!

Answer (score 1):

```
records = [x for x in list(zip(ord, orwh, orob, ornm, orsu, oris))]
cursor.executemany('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO user_data(ord, orwh, orob, ornm, orsu, oris) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)', records)
```

Подсмотрел еще вот такой вариант, тоже помогло

Comment: Выглядит переусложнённо, мне кажется `[x for x in list` тут лишнее, можно просто `records = zip(...` брать. Хотя надо проверять. А если хотите посмотреть, что там, то достаточно и `list(zip(...`